# Check for header in csv and ignore header in php

Tags: php, file-upload, csv, fgetcsv

**I would like to check if csv file contain a header and ignore the header.**

I have to do a check if the first column is not a character

csv file has format : avgTemperature, minTemperature, maxTemperature

> ```
> $f = fopen("./uploads/" .$filename, "r");
> $string = "avgTemperature";
> if (fgetcsv($f)==$string){  
>     // read the first line and ignore it
>     fgets($f);
> }
> ```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: @AleksG...i'm just stuck about how to check if the first line of the csv is a character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going from your comment, and from the idea that the actual data is temperatures (i.e. numeric data), if you do have headers, then they will be text strings and not numbers.  Therefore you can do something like this:

```
$f = fopen("./uploads/" .$filename, "r");

if(!($data = fgetcsv($f))) {
    return;    //most likely empty file
}

if(!is_numeric($data[0])) {
    //this is your header line - skip it - and read the next line
    $data = fgetcsv($f);
}

while($data) {
    //process a line of data
    ...
    //and read the next line
    $data = fgetcsv($f);
}
```

**EDIT:** An alternative version of the last loop would look like this:

```
do {
    //process a line of data
    ...
}
while ($data = fgetcsv($f));
```

Comment: +1 for an alternative to logic within the `while` loop. Although I would suggest streamlining with `while($data = fgetcsv($f))`

Comment: @JasonMcCreary Yes, this could be done, but it will have to be `do-while` loop

Comment: Don't think so friend. `while` always evaluates first. `do/while` evaluates after the first iteration, always running first. Be sure you know the difference.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary Exactly, my friend.  Because you have already read the first row, you have to read/evaluate the next one AFTER the loop body.  Copy/paste my code and run it.

Answer (score 4):

I assume your complete code uses a loop (`while` or `for`).

As such, you have a few options.

- Simply skip the first row *always*.
- Use logic to test for the *header row* then skip.

Either way, [`continue`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php) is the key piece.

**PHP pseudo code:**

```
while (…) {
  if ($row == $header_row) {
    continue;
  }

  // data rows
}
```

#### UPDATE

The logic for determining if the first row is a header row seems like a better solution in your case. You could use the following to test for that.

```
if ($row[0] == 'avgTemperature') {
  // header row
}
```

**Note:** This makes the assumption that the first column of data is *avgTemperature* and it's header is *avgTemperature*. Adjust as necessary.

Comment: I dont want to skip the first row as if the csv does not have header, it will skip the first row of my data.
Im new to php so I dont really know how to check the first column of the csv is a character or float?

Comment: I think the OP's issue is figuring out whether the first row is header row or the first row of data; not how to look over the data.